# Javascript two arraySort returning same result

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

Hello I am new to javascript. Learning about arrays I have issues regarding sorting. First I am sorting according to their birthdate and next I am sorting according to their age. Still I am getting the same result. Please help.

Code:

```
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1711},
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];

const firstSort= inventors.sort((a,b) => a.year > b.year? -1 : 1 );
console.log(firstSort);

const secondSort = inventor.sort((a,b) => (a.year-a.passed > b.year-b.passed) ? -1 : 1);
console.log(secondSort);
```

Here is first output:

```
0: Object { first: "Ada", last: "Lovelace", year: 1815, … }
​
1: Object { first: "Sarah E.", last: "Goode", year: 1855, … }
​
2: Object { first: "Johannes", last: "Kepler", year: 1571, … }
​
3: Object { first: "Marie", last: "Curie", year: 1867, … }
​
4: Object { first: "Isaac", last: "Newton", year: 1643, … }
​
5: Object { first: "Nicolaus", last: "Copernicus", year: 1473, … }
​
6: Object { first: "Albert", last: "Einstein", year: 1879, … }
​
7: Object { first: "Galileo", last: "Galilei", year: 1564, … }
​
8: Object { first: "Hanna", last: "Hammarström", year: 1829, … }
​
9: Object { first: "Katherine", last: "Blodgett", year: 1898, … }
​
10: Object { first: "Max", last: "Planck", year: 1858, … }
​
11: Object { first: "Lise", last: "Meitner", year: 1878, … }
```

Here is second output

```
0: Object { first: "Ada", last: "Lovelace", year: 1815, … }
​
1: Object { first: "Sarah E.", last: "Goode", year: 1855, … }
​
2: Object { first: "Johannes", last: "Kepler", year: 1571, … }
​
3: Object { first: "Marie", last: "Curie", year: 1867, … }
​
4: Object { first: "Isaac", last: "Newton", year: 1643, … }
​
5: Object { first: "Nicolaus", last: "Copernicus", year: 1473, … }
​
6: Object { first: "Albert", last: "Einstein", year: 1879, … }
​
7: Object { first: "Galileo", last: "Galilei", year: 1564, … }
​
8: Object { first: "Hanna", last: "Hammarström", year: 1829, … }
​
9: Object { first: "Katherine", last: "Blodgett", year: 1898, … }
​
10: Object { first: "Max", last: "Planck", year: 1858, … }
​
11: Object { first: "Lise", last: "Meitner", year: 1878, … }
```

Comment: sort mutates the original array, use `inventors.slice(0).sort` and you should have a copy of both

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(firstSort));`

Comment: `sorting according to their age`  Just a heads up, you can't work out a persons age using years only.. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) works upon the return value.

Also, the lifespan period should be calculated as `a.passed - a.year` as `a.passed` is greater than `a.year`

```js
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1711},
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];

const firstSort = inventors.sort((a,b) => a.year - b.year); // exactly the same as a.year > b.year ? 1 : -1;
console.log(firstSort);

const secondSort = inventors.sort((a,b) => (a.passed - a.year) - (b.passed - b.year));
console.log(secondSort);
```

Comment: `Math.sort` ??,  I assume your mean `Array.prototype.sort`

Comment: @Keith thanks. Sometimes what I think isn't what i write.

Comment: Regarding that "year-passed". I changed it to passed - year. But both the variables have same result. After 2 3 hours for some weird reason I found out that my code works in google chrome and is giving this kind of false answer in mozilla firefox. What kind of a bug is this. Weird :|

Answer (score 0):

you can change the condition based on what order you want to get the desired result should be.

First you need to sort by year and then you can sort the sorted array with subtracting the passed and year property and sort it.

I hope the below code will solve your issue.

```js
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1711},
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];
let sortedArr = inventors.sort((a,b) =>(a.year > b.year) ? 1 : ((b.year > a.year) ? -1 : 0)).sort((a,b) => (a.year - a.passed > b.year - b.passed) ? 1 : (b.year - b.passed > a.year - a.passed) ? -1 : 0 )


console.log(sortedArr)
```